# Using jQuery on "native" html objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just started using jQuery, but am a bit stuck. I am building a table dynamically in Javascript and am adding classes all the time to cells (for styling), so I would like to use the `addClass` function:

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.addClass('boldRow');
```

but this does not work. I know you can use the magic `$('')` function to be able to use jQuery, but can I use it on 'native' HTMLElement references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(cell).addClass` should do the trick - why don't you try it and let us know.

In any case you have to use the `$()` to load the jQuery framework to get access to `addClass`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise you could pass DOM objects as well as strings.

Comment: No problem, jQuery tends to pleasantly surprise like that :)

Comment: Yes, it has restored my faith in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You just place the element in like you would a string.

```
$(someElementReference).addClass('boldrow');
```

You can also pass in a collection of elements if that is what you have.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qS473/

Comment: @Callum - Yeah, it's pretty handy. Lots of settings on the left to do things like load different libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass in native DOM objects into the `jQuery` function, and it will create a `jQuery` object from the DOM object:

```
$(cell).addClass('boldRow');
```

**But you don't need `jQuery` to add a CSS class to a DOM object!**:

```
cell.class += ' boldRow';
```

Comment: I know - I'm doing that at the moment :) But it is very annoying to do that each time, and this is very complex table. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Jacob - Don't forget to fix your DOM API version for IE6. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select all HTML elements with $() for example, $('body'), or $('html') etc. Since it's only a framework, you can also use any other Javascript you can think of to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first thing I do when creating a new element is something like this:

```
var newDivJQObject = $(document.createElement('div'))
  .attr('id', '[uniqueID]')
  .addClass('[className]');
```